# Java - MacAddressApplet not working after update to 8u45

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet

In one of my web applications I'm using the `MacAddressApplet`, which can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/macaddressapplet/source/browse/trunk/src/MacAddressApplet.java).

Everything worked fine up to Java 8u31.
Since update to Java 8u45 today it stopped working. The function call to retrieve the MAC address from the applet returns now undefined.

Any suggestions?

Upon "request" here the code: (even though I linked to it above)

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2008-2010. Agwego Enterprises Inc.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * If you modify this software a credit would be nice
 */

import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.security.PrivilegedActionException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class MacAddressApplet extends Applet
{
    public static String sep = ":";
    public static String format = "%02X";

    /**
     * getMacAddress - return the first mac address found
     * separator - byte seperator default ":"
     * format - byte formatter default "%02X"
     *
     * @param ni - the network interface
     * @return String - the mac address as a string
     * @throws SocketException - pass it on
     */
    public static String macToString( NetworkInterface ni ) throws SocketException
    {
        return macToString( ni, MacAddressApplet.sep,  MacAddressApplet.format );
    }

    /**
     * getMacAddress - return the first mac address found
     *
     * @param ni - the network interface
     * @param separator - byte seperator default ":"
     * @param format - byte formatter default "%02X"
     * @return String - the mac address as a string
     * @throws SocketException - pass it on
     */
    public static String macToString( NetworkInterface ni, String separator, String format ) throws SocketException
    {
        byte mac [] = ni.getHardwareAddress();

        if( mac != null ) {
            StringBuffer macAddress = new StringBuffer( "" );
            String sep = "";
            for( byte o : mac ) {
                macAddress.append( sep ).append( String.format( format, o ) );
                sep = separator;
            }
            return macAddress.toString();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * getMacAddressInternal - return the first mac address found
     *
     * @return the mac address or undefined
     */
    protected static String getMacAddressInternal()
    {
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

            // not all interface will have a mac address for instance loopback on windows
            while( nis.hasMoreElements() ) {
                String mac = macToString( nis.nextElement() );
                if( mac != null && mac.length() > 0 )
                    return mac;
            }
        } catch( SocketException ex ) {
            System.err.println( "SocketException:: " + ex.getMessage() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            System.err.println( "Exception:: " + ex.getMessage() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "undefined";
    }

    /**
     * getMacAddressesJSON - return all mac addresses found
     *
     * @return a JSON array of strings (as a string)
     */
    protected static String getMacAddressesJSONInternal()
    {
        try {
            String macs [] = getMacAddresses();

            String sep = "";
            StringBuffer macArray = new StringBuffer( "['" );
            for( String mac: macs ) {
                macArray.append( sep ).append( mac );
                sep = "','";
            }
            macArray.append( "']" );

            return macArray.toString();
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            System.err.println( "Exception:: " + ex.getMessage() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "[]";
    }

    /**
     * getMacAddresses - return all mac addresses found
     *
     * @return array of strings (mac addresses) empty if none found
     */
    public static String [] getMacAddresses()
    {
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

            ArrayList<String> macs = new ArrayList<String>();
            while( nis.hasMoreElements() ) {
                String mac = macToString( nis.nextElement() );
                // not all interface will have a mac address for instance loopback on windows
                if( mac != null ) {
                    macs.add( mac );
                }
            }
            return macs.toArray( new String[macs.size()] );
        } catch( SocketException ex ) {
            System.err.println( "SocketException:: " + ex.getMessage() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            System.err.println( "Exception:: " + ex.getMessage() );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new String[0];
    }

    /**
     * getMacAddresses - return all mac addresses found
     *
     * @param sep - use a different separator
     */
    public static void setSep( String sep )
    {
        try {
            MacAddressApplet.sep = sep;
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            //  don't care
        }
    }

    /**
     * getMacAddresses - return all mac addresses found
     *
     * @param format - the output format string for bytes that can be overridden default hex.
     */
    public static void setFormat( String format )
    {
        try {
            MacAddressApplet.format = format;
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            //  don't care
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wrap the privilege access to our internal method
     */
    private final class MacAddressService implements PrivilegedAction<String>
    {
        public String run()
        {
            return getMacAddressInternal();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wrap the privilege access to our internal method
     */
    private final class MacAddressesJSONService implements PrivilegedAction<String>
    {
        public String run()
        {
            return getMacAddressesJSONInternal();
        }
    }


    /**
     * getMacAddress - return the first mac address found
     *
     * @return the mac address or undefined
     * @throws java.security.PrivilegedActionException ex
     */
    public String getMacAddress() throws PrivilegedActionException
    {
        return AccessController.doPrivileged( new MacAddressService() );
    }

    /**
     * getMacAddress - return the first mac address found
     *
     * @return the mac address or undefined
     * @throws java.security.PrivilegedActionException ex
     */
    public String getMacAddressesJSON() throws PrivilegedActionException
    {
        return AccessController.doPrivileged( new MacAddressesJSONService() );
    }

    public static void main( String... args )
    {
        MacAddressApplet ma = new MacAddressApplet();

        try {
            System.err.println( " MacAddress = " + ma.getMacAddress() );
            System.err.println( " MacAddresses JSON = " + ma.getMacAddressesJSON() );

        } catch( PrivilegedActionException ex ) {
            System.err.println( ex );
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the called function is:

```
getMacAddresses()
```

[EDIT]
The jar is signed with the following manifest:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
Application-Name: CelluPOS
```

Comment: Suggesting roll back to 8u31 ... but seriously, did anything else change, too?

Comment: Rollback on more than 100 terminals is not the best solution....

Comment: Did you inform the devs of the Applet?

Comment: The applet is simple. What should it help to ask the devs? they released it 7 years ago.

Comment: The code, and a clear description of the problem ("it doesn't work" doesn't qualify) must be in the question.

Comment: "The function call to retrieve the MAC address from the applet returns now undefined."

Comment: So where is the code in the question, and what on earth does 'returns now undefined' mean?

Comment: Here's the code... and the called function...;

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant yourself `java.net.NetPermission: getNetworkInformation.`

Comment: actually i have there the setting: Permissions: all-permissions